# Telegram bot handler doesn't process response from another Updater

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have an issue with processing user responses in the telegram bot.
I have a main ConversationHandler running, but also I have some offline processes which also send messages to the chat. So when message is sent from outside - ConversationHandler doesn't process it.

```
# Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    updater = Updater(API_TOKEN)
    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    # Add conversation handler
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', self.start)],
        states={
            InputTypeEnum.SELECTION_INPUT.value: [
                CallbackQueryHandler(self.selection_input),
            ],
            100: [
                CallbackQueryHandler(self.process_out), self.process_out)
            ],
            InputTypeEnum.MEDIA_INPUTS.value: [
                MessageHandler(Filters.photo, self.media_inputs_photo),
                MessageHandler(Filters.video, self.media_inputs_video),
                CallbackQueryHandler(self.media_inputs_button_action),
            ],
            InputTypeEnum.TEXT_INPUT.value: [
                MessageHandler(Filters.text, self.text_input),
            ],
            InputTypeEnum.CAROUSEL.value: [
                CallbackQueryHandler(self.selection_input),
            ],
            ChatStepEnum.STEP_WAIT_FOR_CREATION: [
                MessageHandler(Filters.all, self.wait_for_creation),
            ]
        },
        fallbacks=[
            CommandHandler('exit', self.done)
        ],
        allow_reentry=True,
    )

    dispatcher.add_handler(conv_handler)
    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()
    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()
```

Everything works when I work inside Handler, but messages from outside are ignored.
how I send from outside:

```
updadater = Updater(API_TOKEN)
updater.dispatcher.bot.send_message(chat_id=295908544,
text='You can easily edit the video, change style, music, etc, with the FREE Vimeo Create app, interested?',
reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup([[InlineKeyboardButton('Finish', callback_data='done')]]))
```

last step before i send message from outside (another server) - I invoke this state:

```
    def wait_for_creation(self, update, context):
    """
    Send GIF and request to create a video to API

    @param update: Update object
    @type update: Update
    @param movie_data: Collected data to crete video
    @type movie_data: Dict
    @return: New state number
    @rtype: int
    """

    print('wait for creation')
    movie_data = context.user_data['movie_data']
    content = {
        'sources': [{'url': media_url} for media_url in movie_data['assets']],
        'sender_id': update.message.chat_id,
        'theme_id': movie_data['theme_id'],
        'platform': 'telegram'
    }

    # create_bot_video(None, content)
    update.message.reply_animation(
        animation=open('actions@2x.gif', 'rb'),
        caption='We are almost there.In the meantime, here is a gif'
    )

    return 100
```

Any ideas why Handler can't process my messages from outside?
Thank you

Comment: BTW. THere are no errors, nothing

Comment: "how I send from outside:" - you don't need an `Updater` here, `bot= Bot('TOKEN')` suffices ;)
"So when message is sent from outside - ConversationHandler doesn't process it." - Do you expect the CH to handle the text message "You can easily edit the video …" or do you expect it to handle the CallbackQuery when the user presses the attached button?
Also how do you tell the external process to send the message? How do you make sure that it's sent to the same chat where the conversatino is taking place?